# How to wrap multithreaded C++ library using Python C/API?

Tags: c++, python, pthreads

This is a somewhat long question, but I hope I can express it clearly.

I am trying to wrap a C++ library using Python/C API. The main library, say, *mylib*, has its own object system (it is something like an interpreter for another language ) and uniquely identifies each object in its environment by an *Id*. It creates multiple threads in its `init()` function and does different things on different threads (say creating objects on one thread and interpreting commands in another thread).
Now I am trying to wrap it in two levels:

1. I created a *Dummy* class with the *Id* of an object in mylib. The Dummy constructor actually calls a function in mylib to create a new object and store its Id. Other methods in Dummy class similarly call equivalent functions in mylib. This does not use Python/C API.
2. I created `mylibmodule.cpp`, which uses the Python/C API to provide the functions that will be called from the Python interpreter.

   I call the `init()` function of mylib in `PyMODINIT_FUNC init_mylib()`.

   I code functions like :

   ```
   static PyObject * py_new_Dummy(PyObject* self, PyObject *args){

     // ... process arguments

     return reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(new Dummy);

   }
   ```

Note that the Dummy constructor does call functions in mylib that are executed on threads created by using pthreads.

I compile this into _mylib.so and I have a mylib.py:

```
 import _mylib

 class MyClass(obj):

     def __init__(self, *args)

         self.__ptr = _mylib.py_new_Dummy()
```

Now to the actual problem: I can import mylib in the Python interpreter, but as soon as I try:

```
a = MyClass(some_args)
```

I get a segmentation fault. A gdb backtrace shows

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> __pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x0) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:50

Even funnier is that if I disable spawning multiple threads in the mylib code (still linked with pthreads), I can create MyClass instances, but I get a segmentation violation at exit from the Python interpreter.

The "Thin Ice" section in the Python documentation (http://docs.python.org/extending/) did not enlighten me. I am wondering if I should use PyGILState_Ensure and PyGILState_Release around all Python C/API calls in mylibmodule.cpp. Or should it be Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS?

Can anybody help? Is there any definitive documentation on how exactly Python plays with pthreads?

Comment: You can use CDLL instead. Should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description it doesn't really sound like a threading issue at all: you claim you define the `Dummy` class without using the Python API, but that would mean `Dummy` instances *are not PyObjects*, so the reinterpret_cast will do the wrong thing. You can't create PyObjects by just instantiating a C++ class; you need to play along with Python's object system and create a proper PyType struct and a PyObject struct and properly initialize both. You also need to make sure your refcounts are correct.

Once you have that sorted, the main thing to remember about threads is that any call that touches Python objects or that uses any of the Python API (except the functions to grab the GIL) *must have the GIL acquired*. If any of the threads in your C++ library try to call back to Python code or touch Python objects, the access needs to be wrapped in `PyGILState_Ensure`/`PyGILState_Release`.

Comment: I don't think the typecast is the problem as it is never accessed as a Python object. It is only passed to the C++ wrapper functions back as an argument and cast back to Dummy* before use.

Comment: Also, if I understand the second part of your answer correctly, the functions in mylibmodule.cpp, which _do not_ create any threads by themselves, can safely access Python objects.For example, suppose `int Dummy::getValue(string field)` does use some threading, and in mylibmodule.cpp: `PyObject * py_wrap_getValue(PyObject*self, PyObject* args)` I do `Py_ParseArgTuple(args, "Os", &obj_ptr, &field)` and then call `int value = (reinterpret_cast<Dummy*>(obj_ptr))->getValue(string(field));` then the `Py_ParseArgTuple` _does not_ need to be surrounded by `PyGILState_Ensure/PyGILState_Release`?

Comment: If you return a PyObject* to Python, it *will* be treated as a Python object. Python will assume it is a PyObject struct and modify its refcount. Blindly returning something that isn't actually a PyObject will *do the wrong thing*.

Comment: Whether you need to use `PyGILState_Ensure`/`PyGilState_Release` depends on whether you hold the GIL at the time. When your C function is called from the Python API (as the arguments to `py_wrap_getValue` seem to suggest) it already holds the GIL and you do not need to take any precautions. (You should, on the other hand, *release* the GIL if you perform any blocking calls in that function.)

Comment: You are right about the PyObject*. I am getting segmentation faults at exit - from gdb backtrace I suspect the Python garbage collector is trying to free the memory for the C++ object pointer. I was blindly following an example from the net (felt too lazy to take the trouble of defining PyType structure). I'll follow your advice now. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for the record: to get rid of the segmentation fault at exit, I had to define a `struct` containing the C++ pointer and the corresponding `PyTypeObject`. Also, when returning a new instance from any function, I had to replace `Dummy* ret = new Dummy()` by `DummyStruct * ret = PyObject_New(DummyStruct, &DummyType)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Thomas for pointing out the red herring. The problem was in the initialization of the threads in the C++ side. 
And yes, it did not need any GIL manipulation as the none of the additional C++ threads were accessing Python C/API.